# Android IntentService - too quick to die?

Tags: android, intentservice

I've recently began experimenting with `Android` development by my own accord, but find myself lacking people to ask about such things as a I come to you with today.

See, I've tasked myself with building a small application that counts the amount of times you've received a call within `x` hours.

After a little bit of googling I found that an `IntentService` should be used for something like this (if this is incorrect and I should use a `Service` instead, give me a wink).

I've implemented the n `IntentService`, and gotten it to run through the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    Log.i(info, "The app started!");

    Intent i = new Intent(this, IntentServiceTest.class);
    i.putExtra("KEY1", "information!");
    this.startService(i);

    super.onStart();
}
```

Which, if you didn't guess; happens when my application starts it's first `Activity` (I can post the entire `Activity` if desired).

My `IntentService` looks like this:

```
public class IntentServiceTest extends IntentService {
public IntentServiceTest() {
    super("IntentServiceTest");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(FirstActivity.info, "The IntetService started!");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    Log.i(FirstActivity.info, "Here is some " + workIntent.getExtras().get("KEY1").toString());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(FirstActivity.info, "The IntetService ended!");
}
}
```

Now thus far, I thought I was in on the green. But as some of you sharper minds may have guessed, my `IntentService` does, you know, end. As was revealed to me when my Logcat revealed:

```
I/[INFORMATION]: The IntetService ended!
```

It has not lasted `x` hours, and it certainly hasn't counted any inbound phone calls (though the latter is a problem for another day).

How do I get this `IntentService` to lay dormant in the background, while listening for incoming phone calls?

Every time I click the "Home" button in my emulator, my console tells me that:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7d30a0
```

(Which I'm just guessing is because the `IntentService` is dead?)

Can anyone give me a quick explanation on how to keep my `IntentService` alive over time? Even after the user hits the "Home" button and thus leaves the app?

Comment: "How do I get this IntentService to lay dormant in the background, while listening for incoming phone calls?" -- you don't. `IntentService` is for transactional work, stuff that may take a moment (and therefore needs a `Service`) but that will end in short order. Disk I/O, database I/O, network I/O, and the like are examples of what you use an `IntentService` for.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, then I might have misunderstood the use of the class. What would you recommend to accomplish my goal, if not `IntentService`?

Comment: I have not attempted to track call information, and so I do not know what the appropriate approach would be. That being said, I would recommend starting by determining how you will find out when calls start and stop, then work from there.